# Get class name which throwing exception

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, sharepoint, exception

[Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) class provides so many properties which will provide more meaning full details about raised exception.

*`InnerException-->Gets Exception instance that caused the current exception`*.

*`Message-->Gets a message that describes the current exception.`*

*`Source--> Gets or sets the name of application or object that causes the error.`*

*`StackTrace -->Gets a string representation of immediate frames on the call stack.`*

*`Public property  -->TargetSite Gets the method that throws the current exception.`*

but sometimes it doesn't make any sense.

```
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemById(String strId, Int32 id, String strRootFolder, Boolean cacheRowsetAndId, String strViewFields, Boolean bDatesInUtc) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemById(Int32 id) 
   at JafraWFTest.JafraCustomWFActivity.<Execute>b__0()
```

in this case i don't know the anything nor line number nor class name which is causing the exception.

so **how to find the class name which causing the Exception .**

Answer (score 0):

Please add some clearance to your question.

1. Where do you get exception? Is it your custom code, or workflow in
   SP Designer?
2. Is `JafraWFTest.JafraCustomWFActivity` your code or some 3rd party?
3. Where do you get logs, 14 Hive\Logs ?

> so how to find the class name which causing the Exception .

The class which trows exception is `JafraWFTest.JafraCustomWFActivity`. It's a custom workflow action. The exception is throwing when it's being executed. `<Execute>b__0()` this means that `JafraWFTest.JafraCustomWFActivity` implements generic interface for workflow action with `Execute` method.

So if `JafraWFTest.JafraCustomWFActivity` is your code look for `JafraCustomWFActivity` class in `JafraWFTest` namespace and `Execute` method.
If it's a 3rd party code. Try to look for JafraWFTest assembly (dll) in application BIN directory or GAC. And the other should be the same as for your code case.

From code semantic I assume that it's a test for custom workflow action. Check if JafraWFTest assembly should be installed to GAC for it and test environment (site, list, list items) is properly configured.